# Encryption in objective c using modulus and exponent

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Actually I am trying to call a method that uses my own modulus and exponent but i am getting an invalid argument exception in the below given method.

```
- (NSData *)PublicKeyItems

{      
    NSString *exp = @"010001";
    NSLog(@"Publickeyexp - %@",exp);
    NSData *publickeyexpdata= [self stringasdata:exp];
    NSLog(@"publickeyexpdata = %@",publickeyexpdata);
    NSString *mod = @"008903fb6d15f352ed3b45add3216f632f7139954a5631337aba7d645ed38482e3a810b4db26aab4d1df58c147230f0c75631a3dd0554b50de44e79f4fcf205c89fd3f80e0ff8d16c2e9f56ed3ab177953d54c9c30357d04e677cedd9912906ef8a046d7b0185b7f2022a8e435b0c6ecaef93f089fc3aa3f3677550b5d842046c7";
    NSLog(@"Publickeymod -%@",mod);
    NSData *publickeymoddata= [self stringasdata:mod];
    NSLog(@"publickeymod = %@",publickeyexpdata);

    NSMutableArray *publicarray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
    [publicarray addObject:publickeyexpdata];
    [publicarray addObject:publickeymoddata];

    NSData *testData = [publicarray berData];
    NSLog(@"testdata = %@",testData);
    NSMutableArray *testArray2 = [testData berDecode];
    NSLog(@"testarray = %@",testArray2);

    NSData *testData2 = [testArray2 berData];
    NSLog(@"PublicKeyData using Publickeyitems = %@",testData2);
    return testData2;
}
```

The exception that I am getting is

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM berData]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c49050' "

. I suppose the public array is not able to get berdata.

Comment: You call the Method `berData` on an `NSMutableArray` publicarray, i do not know such a method, and didn't find anything about it in the reference. The exception says your compiler seems to find no method `berData` either. What's it?

Comment: Yes Rene, you are right I just download the source code from https://github.com/StCredZero/SCZ-BasicEncodingRules-iOS In this there is BasicEncodingRules.m that contains the implementation for berData method

Comment: did you import `BasicEncodingRules.h`?

Comment: Yes, I have, and put breakpoints at berData function calling as well as definition of berData. I wonder execution control is not able to reach in the definition of berData.